# How to speparate a text using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for how to separate the text in a MAP in java.
For example I have the following text:

> 2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored) Profile  Description:Set nodev on removable
>   media to prevent character and block special devices that are present
>   , on the removable media from being treated as device files.

So I made the following code using the regex:

```
    String text ="2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored)"
                 +"Profile  Description:Set nodev on removable media to prevent character and "
                 +"block special devices that are present" 
                 +", on the removable media from being treated as device files. ";
     Map<String, List<String>> maps = new HashMap<>();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((\\d+\\.)*?(\\d+)) .*$"); //To find out if there is, for example, 1.1. 
            Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[0-9].*?.*[0-9].*$");//To retrieve the title of the paragraph: 1.1. Add Nodev Option to Removable Media Scores
            List<String> paragraphe = new ArrayList<>();
            maps.put(null, paragraphe); 

            for(String ligne : text.split("\n")) {  

                          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ligne); 
                          Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(ligne); 

                              if ( matcher.matches() && matcher2.matches()) { 

                                       paragraphe = new ArrayList<>(); 
                                       maps.put( matcher2.group(0), paragraphe);
                                       paragraphe.add(ligne); 
                          }
                              else {

                                  paragraphe.add(ligne);
                              }


        }
for (Entry<String, List<String>> key : maps.entrySet()) {
                for (String strings : key.getValue()) {
                    if (strings.contains("(Scored)")) {                 
                        System.out.println("Key : " + key.getKey() + " Value : " + key.getValue());
                    }
                }

            }
```

This code displays the following result:

> **Key :** 2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored)
>
> **Value :** [2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored)
>
> Profile Description:Set nodev on removable media to prevent character
>   and block special devices that are present , on the removable media
>   from being treated as device files. ]

But I want to have the following results: the key containing the title (2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored)) and the value of their content (Profile Description:Set nodev on removable ......):

> **Key :** 2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media Partitions (Scored)
>
> **Value :** [
>   Profile Description:Set nodev on removable media to prevent character
>   and block special devices that are present , on the removable media
>   from being treated as device files. ]

Someone could help me to get the right result.
Thank you

Comment: You split `text` with `\n`, but the `text` has no `\n`.

Comment: Since there isn't really a line delimiter, how do you plan to determine where the title ends and the paragraph starts?

Comment: I want to separate the text without `\n`, for example if the line contains the word " **(Scored)**", so we will only take the contents of this line: **2.10 Add nodev Option to Removable Media (Scored)**

Comment: Please, can you explain better what exactly determines key and description? Is it the string "(Scored)" that marks always key end, or also a "\n" can mark key end? Can description span on multiple lines (separated by "\n")? Does description always start in a new line?

Comment: Each title ends with the keyword " **(Socred)**"
The description of the paragraph begins with a  **new line**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a single regex representing the three parts of a paragraph while grouping them in their own capturing group :

```
((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?.*\(Scored\))\n?(.*)
```

to be used with the DOTALL flag, so

```
Pattern.compile("((\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?.*\\(Scored\\))\\n?(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

The first group is the title, the second group the number at the beginning of the title and the third the body of the paragraph.

I've added a `\n?` to remove the leading linefeed of the body.

You can try it [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BQInUz/1) or on [ideone](https://ideone.com/bqnSwO).

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

If `(Scored)` is the last word in the title, and the text after is the paragraph, then change your regex patterns to:

- For Title:

  ```
  ^((\d+\.)*?(\d+)).*\(Scored\)
  ```

  Added `\(Scored\)` at the end to make sure the title ends with `(Scored)`
- For the paragraph:

  ```
  (?<=\(Scored\) ).*$
  ```

  Added a positive lookbehind `(?<=\(Scored\) )` that makes sure the match is preceded by `(Scored)`.

[Regex101 Demo for Title](https://regex101.com/r/Uj0fWm/1/)

[Regex101 Demo for Paragrapgh](https://regex101.com/r/Uj0fWm/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @degant

Comment: The two solution you proposed it works but I can not accept two solutions at the same time. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace the following line:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((\\d+\\.)*?(\\d+)) .*$");
```

**by**

```
Pattern.compile("((\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?.*\\(Scored\\))\\n?(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL)
```